# Non-project files with ReSharper (SASS)

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass, resharper

I'm running JetBrains ReSharper 8.2 on a project that uses SASS for styling.

I compile my seperate scss files into one file "common.css". This file is not included in the project, but gets compiled on build on the server (grunt + compass takes care of this).

I don't want to include this file, but only my SCSS files in the project. This however causes ReSharper to report a lot of errors ("Unknown CSS class"...) in my views because the file isn't included.

Is there a workaround for this (without disabling css errors in settings)?

I've tried the "ReSharper.ExternalCode" extension (https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/ReSharper.ExternalCode), but without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, there isn't a workaround for this. ReSharper doesn't know about SCSS files, and doesn't know anything about files that aren't included in the project, so it can only assume the CSS classes are undefined.

The external code plugin *should* work and allow ReSharper to process the resulting css file. However, I'm not sure how flexible it is - I *think* it needs everything to be configured before the solution is opened. That is, it only tells ReSharper about the generated file when the solution is being opened. Configuring things while a solution is open *probably* won't be reflected immediately (but I haven't tried it). Similarly, it doesn't notify ReSharper of changes to the file, and I don't think that ReSharper sets up any monitoring. So if the file isn't available when the solution opens, or changes while it's open, ReSharper won't have correct information. I'd try and configure it, close the solution and reopen.